# Returning a list from a function in clojure

Tags: list, function, clojure, return

I want to return a list from a clojure function. How do I do that. I've tried the following:

```
(lst val)
```

This fails because lst is not an `IFn`.

```
'(lst val)
```

This returns a list of two symbols `lst` and `val`. What I want is to return a list which contains the values of `lst` and `val`. How do I do that?

Comment: in addition to the answer, you can also use the following to make a list: `\`(~a ~b)` (notice the first char is not a quote, but a syntax quote: `\``. This way you can splice other sequences into the list: `(let [a 1 b 2 c [:a :b :c]] \`(~a ~@c ~b))` => `(1 :a :b :c 2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a List, just use `list`:

```
(list lst val)
```

Or, unless you really need a List, you can just return a Vector of items:

```
[lst val]
```

If you're just returning a pair of items, I'd personally go with former, although beyond readability, it won't matter in a case like this.